# Esri Popup Wrapper

Tags: editing, esri-geodatabase, popup

How can I edit the attributes shown in the popup wrapper? How can I hide some of the fields?

[image]

Comment: Are you developing with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript? Or with a specific application?  Which fields to display are initially determined by the metadata for the feature service, and applications can be configured to not show specific fields.

Comment: @BjornSvensson, yes I am working with the ArcGIS API for JS. Is there any way to hide the globalID for example? Or that has to be done on the level of the feature service?